# Could not load content for http://x.com/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an HTML CSS Website and I'm getting this error and similar. I've seen a couple of answers where it says that you need to go to Developer Tools in your browser and fix it there but I've tried in every browser and I think the problem is within the code can someone help me with it?

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://envio.ae/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://xxxxxx.com/css/aos.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: since `http://envio.ae/js/bootstrap.min.js` has the final line `//# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.js.map` and `http://envio.ae/js/bootstrap.min.js.map` does not exist, unless that is YOUR site, there's nothing YOU can do about it - if it is YOUR site, then you need to make sure that file exists

Answer (score 5):

Referring to **[Vitaliy-1](https://github.com/Vitaliy-1)**'s soultion [here](https://github.com/pkp/healthSciences/issues/117#issuecomment-450626279). You could either add source map files or remove the source map reference.

This error means that browser can't find the file pointed here: https://github.com/pkp/healthSciences/blob/master/libs/bootstrap.min.css#L7

Source map files, like `bootstrap.min.css.map`, are generated automatically during files minification/compiling process. They actually are not needed for the production, but at the same time occupy 3 times more disk space than ones which they are mapping. That's why I don't include them in the release.

If you want just to remove that message, you can either remove comments like `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */` in `bootstrap.min.css`, `bootstrap.min.js` and `popper.min.js` or download source map files from a Bootstrap 4.1.3 release and put them inside `libs` directory.

Comment: it doesn't work for me ,, the warning still there